# Unicode error when trying to plot arrays?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, unicode

I have a very simple code and am attempting to plot my resulting numpy array `pos` as a function of `t`, but I'm getting a random unicode error. I've never had this error appear before, and I'm at a loss for what it means or why it would appear in this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

h = 0.5
x_0 = 1
w = 1
t = np.arange(0, 20, h)
pos, v = np.zeros(len(t)), np.zeros(len(t))
pos[0], v[0] = x_0, 0

def a(pos):
    return -w**2 * pos

for i in range(1, len(t)):
    # Stormer-Verlet method
    pos[i] = pos[i-1] + h*(v[i-1] + 0.5*h*a(pos[i-1]))
    v[i] = v[i-1] + 0.5*h*a(pos[i-1]) + 0.5*h*a(pos[i])

# Plotting position as a function of time
plt.plot(t, pos, label='Störmer-Verlet approximation')
```

At the `plt.plot` line, I'm getting this error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)`. I also printed `pos` and confirmed that it is an array as expected, with length 100 (the same length as `t`). Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: I think your error is about the special character `ö` you're trying to print with the label value. Try with a normal `o` ?

Comment: Oh wow, I never would've thought to change there. That worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python 2 does not have utf-8 as default encoding. defining your encoding with either of

```
# coding=utf-8
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

should do. refer to [PEP-0263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).

then you need to prefix your label with a [`'u'`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings):

```
plt.plot(t, pos, label=u'Störmer-Verlet approximation')
```

Comment: Also *save* the source file in UTF-8 to match the declared encoding.